# How to upload multiple files with web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to get multiple files with web.py.
The form is something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/addProduct" enctype="mutipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <textarea form="pro-form" name="des"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="icon">
    <input type="file" id="uploadSc" name="screen">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Python code is as follows:

```
class addProduct(Auth):
    def GET(self):
        return render.addProduct()

    def POST(self):
        i = web.input(icon={}, screen={})
        name, address, des, icon, screen =  i.name, i.address, i.des, i.icon, i.screen
        # print icon.filename
        print icon
        icon_dir = './static/product/icon/'
        # icon_dir = saveFile(icon, icon_dir)
        screen_dir = './static/product/screen/'
        # screen_dir = saveFile(screen, screen_dir)

        db.insert(product, pro_name=name, pro_url=address, pro_screenurl=screen_dir, pro_iconurl=icon_dir, pro_desc=des)
        return icon
```

The server simply returns just the filename of the icon, not the value of it:(

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer now...
I've wrong spelled `multipart/form-data`as `mutipart/form-data` here
:(